# Binding actix to unix socket + running on multiple subdomains

Tags: rust, actix-web

I've run into following problem. I want to set up actix on unix socket, that's my preferred way, but I can change that if **really** needed.

Let's say `/etc/server.sock`

My nginx server redirects traffic from few subdomains into this socket
Now, I want to set up few domains preferably on same app to avoid mess.

I've tried setting up `tokio::net::UnixListener`, and passing it into `listen` method.
I've also tried passing everything into one server but then I realized that I can't do that due to fact that routes would collide in few places.

Comment: A quick look in the documentation reveals there are [`.bind_uds()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.HttpServer.html#method.bind_uds) and [`.listen_uds()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.HttpServer.html#method.listen_uds) methods on an `HttpServer`. Do those not accomplish this or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Well you haven't misunderstood it, however since you are redirecting everything to the same server, you are essentially responsible for parsing the 'Host:' part of the HTTP header and figure out where to route it.  May be rethink the design, as you are literally merging the sockets in nginx and then reversing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of friend I managed to find a solution, I have no idea if it's a good way to do it but:

**1.** I've split my files into different routes

```
Api folder (module)
 \---files for all subdomains
main.rs
```

**2.** In main I've set up services for every subdomain

```rs
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(api::a_handler())
            .service(api::b_handler())
            .service(api::c_handler())
            .service(api::d_handler())
    });

    server.bind("127.0.0.1:8000")? //I've also switched from unix sockets
        .run()
        .await
}
```

**3.** Then in every api file I've set up handlers and guards respectively

```rs
pub fn a_handler() -> Scope {
    web::scope("").guard(guard::Header("host", "a.example.com"))
}
```